# DD_belatedPNG.js - how to access the vml object? this is for a PNG image-swap

Tags: internet-explorer-6, png, rollover

I am trying to use Drew Dillard's awesome DD_belatedPNG fix + jQuery to achieve a run-of-the-mill image-swap on hover -- but with PNGs, and to work on IE6.

Example: `<a id="thelink" href="blah.html"><img src="f-u-ie6.png" /></a>`

Since DD's script sets the visibility of the original image to "hidden", you can't effectively hover over it. A lot of people, I have noticed, are thwarted by this limitation. Enough so that Drew mentioned he would try to get a work-around into the next version of his PNG fix.

Well, in the meantime, I thought I could get around this by handling the hover event on the image's parent instead. So onmouseover, I would hide the VML object created by DD_belatedPNG while setting a background image on "thelink", and onmouseout, show the VML object again and set the background image to nothing.

The following code was just to see if I could access the VML object, but it does not work on the VML. It hides all manner of other children, but not the VML. Any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("thelink").hover(function() {
    $(this).children().attr({ 
      style: "visibility:hidden"
    });
  }, function() {
    $(this).children().attr({ 
      style: "visibility:visible"
    });
  });
});
```

Alternatively, can anyone suggest a great PNG image-swap method? I know that you can swap a background image of a link. But you still need to have something inside the A tag. That's not my case. Also, you could put a transparent GIF in the A tag and have the background image swapped to achieve the effect, but I really don't want to do that. Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the innerHTML (using javascript in the browser address bar) and seeing the code that generates the VML object which displays my PNG when using the [DD_belatedPNG](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_belatedPNG/) fix, I decided to take a different tack.

I am now using [TwinHelix's IE PNG Fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/). I have both OFF and ON state PNGs in the A tag, but the ON state images are set to `display: none`. I am using jQuery to toggle these images. See my [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603119/bind-handler-to-elements-in-jquery-object-to-affect-children-of-elements) for specific code.

All this to make sure my PNG rollovers work in IE6.