# bind handler to elements in jQuery object to affect children of elements

Tags: jquery, bind

I want to bind handlers for mouseenter and mouseleave to a set of elements grabbed using the jQuery selector. The function needs to act on the children of the elements.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".topnav-link").bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function() {
        $(this).children(".topnav").toggle();
    });
});
```

and in the body of the html:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>
        <a class="topnav-link" href="some-url">
            <img class="topnav" src="nav-about-us.png" />
            <img class="topnav hidden" src="/images/site/nav-about-us-on.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="topnav-link" href="some-url'}">
            <img class="topnav" src="nav-products.png" />
            <img class="topnav hidden" src="/images/site/nav-products-on.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="topnav-link" href="some-url">
            <img class="topnav" src="nav-contact.png" />
            <img class="topnav hidden" src="/images/site/nav-contact-on.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This actually works fine on Mac/Win/FF/Safari, but on IE6 and IE8, only the first element grabbed by the `$(".topnav-link")` selector displays the desired behavior.

Thanks for any help as to what I'm missing!

Comment: Can you do something simple like just alert('event fired'); inside the bind function, and see if your non-first elements fire the event?

Comment: unless I misunderstand your desired behavior, your above example works fine for me in IE8: jsbin.com/axuve/edit#output

Comment: Thanks for taking a look and commenting, both of you. Matt, after seeing your jsbin example, I realized I had to hunt elsewhere as to why my behaviors weren't being displayed. I feel silly, but it turns out that the fix I was using for my PNGs, was incompletely applied to all but the ones in the first link, and that had an effect on them not toggling correctly.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You should use CSS to achieve the desired roll-over effects.

Please read [CSS Technique: Fast Rollovers Without Preload](http://wellstyled.com/css-nopreload-rollovers.html) for more information.

Comment: Aware of that technique, but...

The design requirement was for clickable nav items in a non-web font (so must be image or SIFR), transparent against a variable background, that changed on hover, all compatible with IE6.

The CSS technique you mention is an obvious choice for simpler scenarios where you would have text in the A tag. In my case, the text had to be part of the image, so using the CSS technique would leave the A tag empty.

Thanks for mentioning it, though. It may be helpful to others who come across this thread looking for a clean, simple hover effect.